# Magento: get variable from custom Model in a phtml file

Tags: model, undefined-variable

I'm trying without success to get a custom variable (from a custom function and a custom Module).

That's why I have tried (in a .phtml file) :

```
$myModel = Mage::getModel('mymodule/MyClass');
$myVar = $myModel->myCustomFunction();
var_dump($myVar);
```

but I get always NULL;

When I write a var_dump in the function I get see the wanted value of the variable, but that don't works in the template file.

Comment: make sure your method returns something.

Comment: Can you post your model function here as well?

Comment: Make sure your model actually references a class with: echo get_class($mayModel);

Comment: Also, your model is not ('mymodule/MyClass') - it should be ('modelgroup/path_to_model')

Comment: silly question but does the function actual return the variable? if you say in the function you can see it? also if you are not doing anything with the variable you could just call `getVariable()`

Comment: generally, you need to pass the variable to block then pass it to phtml file. As everyone said, Please check if your model function is returning something or post your model code so we can check.. thanks